# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token Exception

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I'm trying to put data and sign in a user on ParseUser database, but I get the exception "invalid session token". I'm not sure about the `user.put("fullname", fullname);`.

```
 signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override


        public void onClick(View view) {


            final String email, fullname, username, password;
            email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            fullname = nameEditText.getText().toString();
            username = usernaEditText.getText().toString();
            password = passEditText.getText().toString();

            if (!(email.isEmpty() || fullname.isEmpty() || username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())){
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();

                user.put("fullname", fullname);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setPassword(password);


                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {

                       if (e == null){
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Sign up successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                           if(e.getCode() == 202){
                               emailEditText.setText("");
                               nameEditText.setText("");
                               usernaEditText.setText("");
                               passEditText.setText("");
                           }
                           Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Sign up failed "+ e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                });
```

[This is the exception that the Toast shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5ObU.jpg)

Comment: I've got this, just you have to log out with the current user, just put the code before `ParseUser user = new ParseUser();`  `ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.logOut();`

Answer (score 0):

I've got this, just you have to log out with the current user, just put the code before `ParseUser user = new ParseUser();`

`ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.logOut();`